# NMap - running as root yields different response than running as another user

Tags: permissions, users, nmap

```
nmap -eeth1 [hostname] -p80
```

Running that command as root uses interface one and fails as expected (interface one is on a subnet blocked by the host.) Using interface 0 succeeds as it should.

However, if I switch to user zabbix then the above command succeeds no matter which valid interface I specify.  If I specify a nonexistent interface it fails as expected.

Any idea why the output is different between root and the zabbix user?

Comment: Use -S to "spoof" the address of the second interface does appear to work, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have something to do with requiring superuser privileges to set new routes.  Regular users can't add new routes via `route` either.  The non-privileged zabbix user is likely failing over to using the default routing table, but nmap is not generating a warning about it.